Particle system shows on emitter mode but not on hair mode?
trying to make some grass on a plane. CtrlA done and Particle system added. On emitter it works as it should, on Hair mode, I get three straight lines flat on the XY plane... What is wrong here? Blender 3.4

Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/



weird, it works for me, see what it gives when I open your file: https://zupimages.net/up/24/37/7yuk.jpg

could it be hardware?

maybe, I can't tell

Where to go from here? hmm
